# Trying to handle external services/directives, get uncaught object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to import external directives and services to my angular app. Haven't quite figured it out yet. Still learning Angular.

I have a simple app:

```
  var app = angular.module('imageRepo', ['fileModelDirective','fileUploadService']);

  app.controller('indexController',['$scope', 'fileUpload', function ($scope, fileUpload)   
  {
        $scope.uploadFile = function (tag) {
             var file = $scope.myFile;
             console.log("File: " + JSON.stringify(file) + "\nTag: " + tag);
             fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file,tag,'/api/file');
         }
  }])
```

And my service:

```
angular.module('fileUploadService').
service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function (file,tag,uploadUrl) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    fd.append('tag',tag);
    $http.post(uploadUrl,fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type':undefined}
    }).
    success(function () {
        alert('SUCCESS!!!');
    }).
    error(function () {
        alert("ERROR!!!");
    });
}
}]);
```

And finally my directive:

```
angular.module('fileModelDirective').
directive('fileModel',['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            var model = $parse(attributes.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
   }
}]);
```

As I load this into my browser (Chrome) i get "uncaught object". There's some obvious error here but as a noob with angular I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error might be coming from a missing parameter when declaring the modules. You need to specify its dependencies (even if there are none):

```
var module = angular.module('fileUploadService',[]);
```

I usually structure my modules like so:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',['controllers', 'directives']);
var controllers= angular.module('controllers',[]);

controllers.controller('someController', function($scope) {

});

controllers.controller('anotherController', function($scope) {

});
```